# Pickaxe, Well Grounded Rubyist, --- Fill in my next book ---

Tags: ruby

Trying to master Ruby (not rails yet). What book would you recommend reading next?

1. Pickaxe
2. Well Grounded Rubyist
3. ?

My background... I have a CS degree, I feel like I have absorbed the first two books and am getting quite comfortable with Ruby. I want to get better at the Ruby language before I head into Rails.

Comment: what stage are you currently at (i.e. how strong are you with Ruby?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a good book for learning Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549394/whats-a-good-book-for-learning-ruby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next I'd recommend "Eloquent Ruby" (Russ Olsen) and "Ruby Best Practices" (Greg Brown).